# Using .bind with private functions and constructors

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, call, bind

I have a private function that I use with several public functions. Basically the public functions are shortcuts to add something to an object. Like:

```
function Basket () {
  this.apple = [];
  this.orange = [];
}

// Private
var _add = function ( to ) {
   this[to].push( new Fruit(to) );
}

// Public
Basket.prototype.addApple = function () {
  _add.call( this, 'apple' );
}

Basket.prototype.addOrange = function () {
  _add.call( this, 'orange' );
}
```

I want to remove the `.call` and use `.bind` instead. But doing something like:

```
var _add = function ( to ) {
   this[to].push( new Fruit(to) );
}.bind( Basket );
```

This won't work since it will bind it to the constructor function not the object instance.

Is this even possible to achieve? Or should is using `.call` better? Or is my design pattern messed up!?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to need any binding at all. Why not this ?

```
function Basket () {
  this.apple = [];
  this.orange = [];
}

// Private
var _add = function ( basket, to ) {
   basket[to].push( new Fruit(to) );
}

// Public
Basket.prototype.addApple = function () {
  _add( this, 'apple' );
}

var b = new Basket();
b.addApple();
```

Comment: Yes, if I add the private function to the object. But I do not want to do this :)

Comment: @distractedBySquirrels Oh, I get your question now!

Comment: @distractedBySquirrels I edited. Is that what you want ?

Comment: but now it is like using 'call`. But maybe yours is cleaner than using `call` :-/

Comment: You could also use _add.bind(this)('apple');